# Where to android:filterTouchesWhenObscured?

Tags: android

Headsup! The following question might be a very silly question.

I know from API level 9 Android has introduced android:filterTouchesWhenObscured to prevent tap jacking in Android apps.

My question is will it be enough if I add this attribute to the root of a layout file or do I have to add this to each view inside a layout file?

Which one is advisable?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:filterTouchesWhenObscured

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:filterTouchesWhenObscured):

If `android:filterTouchesWhenObscured` is set to `true`, the `View` will not receive touches whenever view's window is obscured by another visible window.

> My question is will it be enough if I add this attribute to the root of a layout file or do I have to add this to each view inside a layout file?

Yes, it'll be enough to add this attribute to the root of the `layout` file. However, only the area covered by overlapping `View` won't be touchable.

For more details, you can also read "Security" section under [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View)

Comment: It is not working, In some custom ROM devices like Vivo V7 pro's default system keyboard.